# jquery mobile pass parameters with localStorage and function bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a new comer to Jquerymobile.

I have a listview in pageMain and want to show details for each listed items when user click it.

My code is:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="personList">
            <li><a href="#person" id="Jack" age=20>Jack</a></li>
            <li><a href="#person" id="Sam" age=30>Sam</a></li>
        </ul>          
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="person">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div>Name: <div id="myValue">xxx</div>Age: <div id="myAge">xxx</div> </div>   
    </div>
</div>



$("#person").live("pageshow", function onPageShow(e,data){
    //alert("here");
    $("#myValue").text(localStorage.getItem("nameStr"));
    $("#myAge").text(localStorage.getItem("ageStr"));
});

$('#personList li a').live('click', function () {
    //alert("here");
    localStorage.setItem("nameStr",$(this).attr("id"));     
    localStorage.setItem("ageStr",$(this).attr("age"));
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle link for this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hlblade/uj7JZ/)

But it doesn't work, can anybody help me?

Comment: [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is [removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed) in [jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/), use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead

Comment: ^^That.  I just changed that one thing and your jsfiddle example works.

Comment: Thks above, it works well now!